# Fastest way to create a NumPy ndarray by copying from a pointer (not creating a view)

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I need to marshal data represented as native memory into an `ndarray`. I want to copy the native data so that I can deallocate it after the copy.

Performance is a significant concern. What's the fastest way to copy from native memory into a new ndarray?

Comment: What are the alternatives that you've explored?

Comment: Ideally I would like to create an `ndarray` and obtain a pointer to it's contents. I could not find out how to do that with NumPy. I'm also open to any other solution.